# Can someone share a full working example of django inline formset?

Tags: python, django

I have searched the net, I could not find something that's exhaustive. I have several inlineformsets working on the admin, but we now need to move them to custom views.

Answer (score -1):

```
class ServiceImageInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model =  ServiceImage
    extra = 0

class ServiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name', )}
    inlines = [ServiceImageInline]
admin.site.register(Service, ServiceAdmin)
```

Comment: Please read this question. I need a solution for the views, not the admin